# JQuery drag and drop after load() - drag working but drop broken

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, load

I've got a simple jquery setup involving some divs with images and some text which needs to be dragged on to the images. If I run the page on its own, everything is fine. Unfortunately, the way I have things set up, this is an html page which is loaded by jQuery load() into a div on a parent page and when I do this, although the drag works, the drop doesn't. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.draggable').live('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).draggable({start:
            function(){
               //identifies dragged item
            }
         })
     })
     $('.droppable').live('mouseover', function() {
         $(this).droppable({drop: 
             function(){
                //checks to see if it wants dragged item                
             }
          })
     })
});
```

Edit:

Sorry if I was unclear - I'll do my best to clarify: I've got a parent page which has a div into which I'm loading other pages, using the jQuery load function. This parent page is largely empty apart from navigation. All the action goes on on the subordinate pages which are being loaded into it. With regard to the loading, there's nothing fancy going on there - the pages are all loading fine - so I can either look at the loaded pages on their own (opening them directly in a browser) or look at them as they're loaded into the parent page. And that's where there seems to be something screwy, with drag working but drop not. The loading on the parent page is done by:

```
$('.unit-nav-links').bind('click', function() {
    var $sender = $(this);
    $('.content').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $('.content').load($sender.attr('href'), function () {
            $('.content').fadeIn(200, function() {
                currentIndex = parseInt($sender.attr('data-currentIndex'));
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
})
```

where `content` is the div holding the page being loaded and `href` is the address of the page being loaded.

---

Edit: I've found a solution to this one so in the unlikely event that someone stumbles on this it turns out that the problem was with dragging

elements onto  elements. For reasons I can't begin to guess at, when calling the page through jQuery load, this doesn't work, though dragging

onto

or  onto  is fine, so the solution is just to wrap the images in

tags and Bob's your uncle. At least I hope he is.

Comment: I have the same problem ! how did you fix it i cant get it working

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse events are both mouseover. Try switch them to mousedown to start the drag and and mouseup to end it.

Comment: Cheers but I'm still getting the same problem: everything is OK when loaded independently but when loaded into a parent div by jquery, dropping is broken.

Comment: So is the code above with or without the parent div? Show the code which is having problems.